# Can someone explain why I get this error with types?

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, memcpy

I'm more or less new using pointers in C, so sorry if I make some horrible mistakes! In this case, I'm just trying to copy all the elements of a float vector into another.

I have the following chunk of code inside my ***main.c*** file, which works fine:

```
/* NOTE: hash_list is a global variable*/
void insertDataIntoOurHashList(int dia, int delay, char *aeO, char *aeD){
    unsigned int numHash;
    ListData *listData;

    numHash = getHashValue(aeO);

    /* If there's no list yet in this position, then... */
    if (hash_list[numHash] == NULL) {
        hash_list[numHash] = malloc(sizeof(List));
        initList(hash_list[numHash]);
        listData = malloc(sizeof(ListData));
        listData->key = malloc(sizeof(char*)*strlen(aeD)+1);
        strcpy(listData->key, aeD);
        listData->key_sec = malloc(sizeof(char*)*strlen(aeO)+1);
        strcpy(listData->key_sec, aeO);
        listData->numTimes = 1;
        listData->retrasos = (float*) malloc(sizeof(float)*7);
        listData->retrasos[dia-1] = delay;
        insertList(hash_list[numHash], listData);
    }
    else {
        listData = findList2(hash_list[numHash],aeD,aeO);

        /* If already exists a data with both equals keys, then... */
        if (listData != NULL) {
            listData->numTimes++; // We add in one the counter of the list
            listData->retrasos[dia-1] = listData->retrasos[dia-1] + delay / 2;
        }
        /* If exists a data with the same aeD as primary key but not with the aeO as secundary key, then... */
        else {
            listData = malloc(sizeof(ListData));
            listData->key = malloc(sizeof(char*)*strlen(aeD)+1);
            strcpy(listData->key, aeD);
            listData->key_sec = malloc(sizeof(char*)*strlen(aeO)+1);
            strcpy(listData->key_sec, aeO);
            listData->numTimes = 1;
            listData->retrasos = (float*) malloc(sizeof(float)*7);
            listData->retrasos[dia-1] = delay;
            insertList(hash_list[numHash], listData);
        }
    }
    free(aeO);
    free(aeD);
}
```

***ListData *listData*** is a pointer that points to a structure defined in my ***linked-list.h*** file, and **_hash_list_** is a vector of pointers of type ***List*** where each one points to a list of type ***List***, defined in the same file:

```
/**
*
* The TYPE_LIST_KEY is used to define the type of the primary
* key used to index data in the list.
*
*/

#define TYPE_LIST_KEY char*

/**
 *
 * This structure holds the information to be stored at each list item.  Change
 * this structure according to your needs.  In order to make this library work,
 * you also need to adapt the functions compEQ and freeListData. For the
 * current implementation the "key" member is used search within the list.
 *
 */

typedef struct ListData_ {
  // The variable used to index the list has to be called "key".
  TYPE_LIST_KEY key;
  char *key_sec;
  // This is the additional information that will be stored
  // within the structure. This additional information is associated
  // to the key. You may include any field you may need useful.
  float *retrasos;
  int numTimes;
} ListData;

/**
*
* The item structure
*
*/

typedef struct ListItem_ {
  ListData *data;
  struct ListItem_ *next;
} ListItem;

/**
*
* The list structure
*
*/

typedef struct List_ {
  int numItems;
  ListItem *first;
} List;
```

Then, back in my ***main.c*** file, I loop through every cell in my **_hash_list_** , passing the list that pointer of that cell points to, to a function that takes the data from the list and pass them to another function, I mean:

```
void insertInHash(){
  int i;

  for(i = 0; i < HASH_SIZE; i++){
    if (hash_list[i] != NULL) {
      dumpList2(hash_list[i]);
    }

  }
}

/* This function is called for every cell while looping the hash_list */
void dumpList2(List *l){
  ListItem *current;

  current = l->first;

  while (current != NULL)
  {
    insertDataIntoOurTree(current->data->key_sec, current->data->key, current->data->retrasos);
    current = current->next;
  }

}


void insertDataIntoOurTree(char *aeO, char *aeD, float *delays){
  List *list;
  ListData *listData;
  int i;

  /* Case when the node exists! */
  if (treeData != NULL) {
    treeData->num++; // We add in one the counter of treeData
    listData = findList(treeData->list, aeD); // We check if the new destination airport is inside the list of the node...

    /* If the destination is inside the list... */
    if(listData != NULL)
      listData->numTimes++; // We add in one the counter of the list

    /* If the destination isn't inside... */
    else {
      /* We create and initialize the new item the list of the node will contain! */
      listData = malloc(sizeof(ListData));
      listData->key = malloc(sizeof(char*)*strlen(aeD)+1); // Counting with the final '\0' byte!
      strcpy(listData->key, aeD); // Remember the case as above with aeO and aeD
      listData->numTimes = 1;
      listData->retrasos = (float*) malloc(sizeof(float)*7);
      //listData->retrasos[dia-1] = delay; // minus one cos we don't want to be out of bound! ;)
      //copyDelays(listData->retrasos, delays);
      for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        listData->retrasos[i] = 0.0;
      }
      copyDelays(listData->retrasos, delays);

      insertList(treeData->list, listData);
    }
  }
  /* THERE ARE MORE CASES DOWN HERE, BUT THEY DON'T MATTER NOW... */

}
```

The function ***copyDelays*** is defined in my ***linked-list.c*** file:

```
void copyDelays(float *delaysToCopy, float *delays){
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    if (delaysToCopy[i] == 0.0) {
      memcpy(delaysToCopy[i], delays[i], sizeof(float));
    }
  }
}
```

And finally, when I try to compile all my files, I get this error that I don't understand:

```
linked-list.c:234:14: error: passing 'float' to parameter of incompatible type 'const void *'
      memcpy(delaysToCopy[i], delays[i], sizeof(float*));
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/secure/_string.h:65:59: note: expanded from macro 'memcpy'
  __builtin___memcpy_chk (dest, src, len, __darwin_obsz0 (dest))
                                                      ^~~~
/usr/include/secure/_common.h:38:55: note: expanded from macro '__darwin_obsz0'
#define __darwin_obsz0(object) __builtin_object_size (object, 0)
                                                  ^~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [linked-list.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Whats wrong with `delaysToCopy[i] = delays[i];`? `delaysToCopy[i]` and `delays[i]` are floats, not pointers.

Comment: Then if I make a **_free()_** or **_delete_** of '**_delays_**' vector, my '**_delaysToCopy_**' will still have the values inside? @tkausl

Comment: Yes, why wouldn't it? `memcpy(dest, source, sizeof(float));` where both `dest` and `source` are float-pointers is _equivalent_ to `*dest = *source;`.

Comment: you're right @tkausl , I misunderstood concepts and made myself a mess, trying to do something like the answer below...Anyway, thanks! Now I understand much clearer this concepts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the arguments you passed to memcpy() function do not match with the function's signature. memcpy() function signature is as follows: (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/)

```
void * memcpy ( void * destination, const void * source, size_t num );
```

As you see it takes pointers as its first and second arguments, whereas `delaysToCopy[i]` and `delays[i]` are not pointers just float.

It should solve your problem if you use ampersand sign to get their addresses, as shown below:

```
memcpy(&delaysToCopy[i], &delays[i], sizeof(float));
```

Comment: Thank you so much @J. Matt this explanation has made me understand the problem as it seems I've misunderstood the concepts with pointers in this case...